# Rotate UIImageView just like in the Photos.app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation

I am not sure if this has been directly asked before but I apologize if it has. Pretty much all I trying to accomplish is to rotate a UIImageView that is a **subview** within a UIScrollView the same exact way it is in the Photos.app.

There are many links around S.O that show code to rotate the image itself but I am not sure if that is the way it is done in the Photos.app.

If anyone can clear up the way it is done in the Photos.app that would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean with the photo app, but there are not too many ways to rotate a view. Basically there are 2 ways: the first way would be to apply a CGTransformation like in the following example:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];
        [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"polaroid_spacer"]];
        [self addSubview: imgView];
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f delay:5.f options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn animations:^{
            [imgView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2)];
        } completion:NULL];
```

The other way would be to apply a CATransform to the view's layer:

```
//be sure to include quartz
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200)];

    [imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"polaroid_spacer"]];

    [self addSubview: imgView];

    CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    [anim setToValue: [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D: CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0, 0, 1)]];
    [anim setDuration: 3.f];
    [anim setBeginTime: (CACurrentMediaTime() + 5.f)];
    [imgView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"myAwesomeAnim"];
```

Both can be used to accomplish this. But if you don't know too much about Core Animation you should use Core Graphics. It's easier to get some results with that because you can for example use the UIView animations.

Comment: What I mean in the photos app is go look a photo in apple's own photo app and click edit. Then click the arrow to rotate the image and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Ah, now I got it. But yes you can do this the way I described. But they are not just rotating but scaling the image.